# Primefaces lineChart - Limit the number of x-labels

Tags: jsf, primefaces, linechart

In a JSF webpage, I display a line chart thanks to Primefaces. 
Each point corresponds to a date for abscissa and his value. Problem is when I start to display too much points, all x-labels (dates) are printed and user is unable to read them.

Is there a way to limit the number of labels printed to avoid labels overlays?

Comment: This is primefaces question. Why have you tagged it richfaces?

Comment: Sorry. It's because I work with richfaces and primefaces at the same time so I  was certainly confused.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces axis labels are determined by the `ChartModel` backing them. So to manage your situation

1. Limit the entries in the `LineChartModel` to a manageable number
2. Increase the size of your chart as a whole, using it's `width` and `height` css values under the `style` attributes
3. Use the `max X` or `max Y` to restrict value displayed on the corresponding axes

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that there is not limited number of values for the X-abscissa. It could have hundred of values or just less than ten values. 
For 1., it's a solution but the chart will miss of precision. 
2., I can't, because the chart will exceed the size of the screen. 3., max X not working in my case.
I think there is no solution... Primefaces uses jqplot to draw charts, right? Maybe a solution is to modify jqplot source code to not display all x-values...